# Empty ChoiceField selection in Django forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a dropdown form for one to select their graduation year --

```
graduation = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x,str(x)) for x in graduation_range])
```

How would I add an additional field and make that the default selection/display? For example, something like "Select Year".

Currently, I'm doing --

```
graduation_range = range(1970,2015)
graduation_range.append('Select Year')
```

But it seems there must be a more straight-forward way to do this.
 Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add:

```
(u'', u'Select Year')  # First element will be the `value` attribute.
```

So:

```
choices = [(u'', u'Select Year')]
choices.extend([(unicode(year), unicode(year)) for year in range(1970, 2015)])
graduation = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices)
```

BTW, I used `unicode` because you were using `str`, but in practice a year field should probably be an integer, since all years are integers.

Comment: And what happens when the field is required? Then even if the user doesn't select a value then the form is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

```
#city choices
city_list=city.objects.all()
choices_city = ([('----select----','----select a city----')])
choices_city.extend([(x,x) for x in city_list])
city =forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=choices_city))
```

I used it for django 1.8