# Is there a way to put an empty_label in a Django Select field for a non-modelform?

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to use a placeholder in a Django Select field, but I don't want to include it in the options.

I've created an empty field like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6085935/2532070

```
choices = [(u'', u'Select Year')]
choices.extend([(unicode(year), unicode(year)) for year in range(1970, 2015)])
graduation = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices)
```

And this answer covers the `empty_label` argument of a `ModelForm`: [Customize/remove Django select box blank option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739260/customize-remove-django-select-box-blank-option)

But mine is a regular Django form. Is there a way to make the default button render "Select Year" but not include "Select Year" in the dropdown list? Thanks!

Comment: Just render the first option like answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/select-placeholder

Comment: Why not just use "Select Graduation Year" as the label for the `graduation` input? Any particular reason why you need an empty first choice instead of letting the first choice be an accepted value?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to add some kind of autocomplete to the form field ? I'll tell you 2 different ways to do this, but depending on what are you trying to do one is better than the other.

**First Way**

This way is the "generic", if you're trying to use something like `select2` your best answer is the second way

```
choices = [
    (u'', u'Select Year'),
    (u'1', u'1231'),
    (u'2', u'1232')
    (u'3', u'1233')
]
class your_form(forms.Form):

    year = forms.ChoiceField(choices=YEAR_CHOICES, required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(your_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)            
        self.fields['year'].queryset = YEAR_MODEL.objects.none()
        self.fields['year'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _(u'Select Year')})
```

**Second Way**

If you're trying to add a select2 via AJAX you need to receive a non-select field in the template, so you'll need something like:

```
class your_form(forms.Form):

    year = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(your_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)            
        self.fields['year'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _(u'Select Year')})
```

---

The difference between the first way and the second is that the first way the field `year` is a `ChoiceField` that we overwrite the `__init__` function to make the selector empty, and the second one is just a `CharField` that we can manage as we need (this way is just in case you're trying to use a select2 Autocomplete via AJAX)

In both examples we initialize the text box using:

`self.fields['year'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _(u'Select Year')})`

inside the `__init__` overwrite